# Contact Form 7: Redirecting on a condition?

Tags: redirect, plugin-contact-form-7

I am doing a survey using the plugin "Contact Form 7". I want to insert an acceptance box. ONLY if people check this box and click "submit", they should be redirected to another page, where I am going to ask for their e-Mail-addresses.

If they don't check "acceptance" there should be no redirecting.

How can I do this?

I ready inserted on_sent_ok: "location = "" - BUT: This ignores if the acceptance box is 
check or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer myself:

Redirecting without a condition
When you use the Wordpress plugin “Contact Form 7” you can redirect the user to another page after submitting the answers by the follwing code:

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://www.redirectedpage.com');"
```

The line of code you have to copy into the “settings” box at the end of a specific form you created.

Redirecting on a condition
If you want to make the redirecting depending on a specific answer, you can use the following code:

```
on_sent_ok: " if (document.getElementById('car').value=='yes') {location.replace('http://www.redirectedpage1.com')} else { location.replace('http://www.redirectedpage2.com/') } "
```

The code in bold letters has to be changed by your settings.

For example: The question with the id “car” has two possible answers: “Yes” or “No”. If a person selects “Yes” he or she should be redirected to “http://www.redirectedpage1.com”. If “No” is selected, the user should be redirected to “http://www.redirectedpage2.com/”.

Comment: For future readers, `on_sent_ok` is deprecated now :) Please use [DOM Events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) as suggested [here](https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/)

Answer (score 2):

Just write the code into additional setting of contact from 7 as bellow :

```
on_sent_ok: "var Iso = $("input[name=radio-565]:checked").val() ; if(Iso == 'value1' ){ location = 'www.example.com'; } if(Iso == 'value2' ){ location = 'www.example2.com'; }"

####
input[name=radio-565] = radio button name
value1 = radio button 1st value 
value2 = radio button 2nd value
```

Comment: Please don't just post a code, try to add some explanation - how the code is working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybee this helps:

http://drzaus.com/snippet/wordpress-is-contact-form-7-missing-on_submit-callback

here on submit event you can check if *acceptance* imput is checked and then redirect them with

```
window.location = 'http://example.com/your-another-page';
```